# redirect https to http without postdata loss

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

On my website some pages are secure and some are not. I have a search form on each of my page (as a part of a template) and when I'm on https page and launch the search, the results page shows nothing. I know I must be loosing my posted data because of the redirection. Would excluding the results page from being redirected solve my problem? I want it to be http at all times. If that's the case - what exactly do I need to put inside of my .htaccess?

Comment: Use a `307 Temporary Redirect`. That should keep make the browser resend the POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ensure the search form uses 'http:searchurl' in the action rather than just 'searchurl' then it should work